# URL path of image file stored on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I stored an image file on Google Cloud in my Google Cloud Storage bucket. I wish to display this image on my website, what url do I use ?

Answer (score 1):

When you upload an image file to your bucket and then make that image publicly accessible, a URL is shown within the GCP Console that you can then use.

Full details on performing this task and more background information can be found at the GCP Google Cloud Storage page called [Making data public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public).